# Format range as table in Excel 2003

Tags: c#, .net, interop, excel-2003

The following code written for Excel 2007 formats a range as a table without issue.

```
SourceRange.Worksheet.ListObjects.Add(XlListObjectSourceType.xlSrcRange,
            SourceRange, System.Type.Missing, XlYesNoGuess.xlYes, System.Type.Missing).Name = TableName;
            SourceRange.Worksheet.ListObjects[TableName].TableStyle = TableStyleName;
            SourceRange.AutoFilter(1, Type.Missing, XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd, Type.Missing, true);
            if (IsGroupTable)
            {
                SourceRange.Rows.Group(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            }
```

When I try to use the same code in Excel 2003, I get the following error:

```
Type : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Member not found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020003 (DISP_E_MEMBERNOTFOUND))
Source : mscorlib
Help link : 
ErrorCode : -2147352573
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : System.Object ForwardCallToInvokeMember(System.String, System.Reflection.BindingFlags, System.Object, Int32[], System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.MessageData ByRef)
Stack Trace : at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListObjects.Add(XlListObjectSourceType SourceType, Object Source, Object LinkSource, XlYesNoGuess XlListObjectHasHeaders, Object Destination)
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error to occur, is it salvageable?

Answer (score 1):

ListObject has been heavily changed moving up to 2007. I suggest you look at the [changes to ListObject here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225807%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to figure out what it is your trying to use that 2003 doesn't support.